# Cypress test freezes after hovering on snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress

I'm quite new to cypress so I'm not sure what could have caused this, using "cypress open" the sample test successfully completes, but as soon as I hover over any of the DOM snapshots the test runner immediately freezes. Interestingly if the devtools are open they are still usable, but I cannot open them after it has frozen.
Test:

```
describe("messages", ()=>{
    beforeEach(()=>{
        cy.loginWithoutUI();
        cy.intercept("GET", `${Cypress.env("API")}/messages/*`, {fixture:"messages/GET_client-messages.json"});
        cy.intercept("GET",`${Cypress.env("API")}/messages/conversations*`, {fixture:"messages/GET_conversations--page0-5.json"})
        cy.intercept("GET",`${Cypress.env("API")}/labels`, {fixture:"labels/GET--default.json"})
        cy.intercept("GET",`${Cypress.env("API")}/users/networks`, {fixture:"user/GET_networks--default-5.json"})
        cy.intercept("GET",`${Cypress.env("API")}/templates`, {fixture:"templates/GET--default-3"});
        cy.intercept("GET", `${Cypress.env("API")}/clients/*`, {fixture:"client/GET--default.json"});
        cy.intercept("POST", `${Cypress.env("API")}/messages`, (req) => {
        req.reply({ ...req.body});
        });
        cy.visitNoSW("/chat");
    })

    it("Should show client messages, updating dialogue and chat list on new message", ()=>{
        cy.getByData('dialogue').should("exist");
        cy.getByData('message').should("have.length", 8)
    })
})
```

Commands:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("loginWithoutUI", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("userToken","token");
    localStorage.setItem("expDate", Date.now() + 3600000);
    cy.intercept("GET", `${Cypress.env("API")}/users/me`, {fixture:"user/GET_me--complete.json"})
});

Cypress.Commands.add("visitNoSW", (path)=>{
    cy.visit(path, {
        onBeforeLoad (win) {
          delete win.navigator.__proto__.serviceWorker
        }
      })
});

Cypress.Commands.add("getByData", (string)=>{
     cy.get(`[data-cy=${string}]`)
});
```

Is there something wrong with my code here that's causing it to break with no indication as to why?
[image]

Here is the printout of my command log, hovering over any over the XHR values causes the entire app to crash.
I'd love to get this resolved if anyone has any idea what could be wrong. I'd also like to not have to add
"numTestsKeptInMemory": 0 to the config and lose the debugging perks, and since this is such a small test it end up masking a larger problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue. I have even reduced my test to just login into the app and yet cypress still crashes as soon as I hover over the snapshots.